Sorting on a nested field in a jsonb object whose parent key can be multiple values
I have a field that is of type jsonb that is structured like:



data




{    "prices": {        "[parent key]": {            "price": 20        }    }}



[parent key] can be 5 possible values but all I really need is the price field. Ultimately I would like to extract that price field as well as order the results by that field. Is there a way that this can be done?
Example: I would like to get the price for each entry in descending order according to price.
create table my_table(
  id int generated by default as identity primary key,
  data jsonb);
insert into my_table select * from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::my_table,
'[{
  "id": 1,
  "data": {
    "prices": {
      "x": {"price": 20}
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "data": {
    "prices": {
      "y": {"price": 86}
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "data": {
    "prices": {
      "z": {"price": 21},
      "b": {"price": 41}
    }
  }
}]');

If an entry has more than one parent key for 'price', select the larger of the two, returning:
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "price": 86
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "price": 41
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 20
  }
]


Add sample data and expected result, so the community is able to help.

I edited the main post to add an example

I'm a bit confused: is this all one single jsonb object you want to sort? Or is it separate rows? Can you give an actual CREATE TABLE and INSERT example? Also actual JSON formatting with proper quoting.


distinct on(id)..order by id,price desc instructs Postgres to pick one value per id, selecting it by the highest price.
data @? $.prices.*.price will use the index on data column to avoid processing rows that don't have that price key.
jsonb_path_query(data,'$.prices.*.price') already mentioned by @jjanes uses a JSONPath * wildcard where you're unsure what the parent key of price is. It returns all matches from each row, out of which distinct on will pick the one, highest price.

If you mean to get that one long literal jsonb array as output, aggregate with jsonb_agg(). Using to_jsonb() you can automatically map entire rows of the subquery to objects in that array and have it internally sorted by price:
demo at db<>fiddle
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(subquery)order by price desc)
from(select distinct on(id)id
           ,jsonb_path_query(data,'$.prices.*.price')as price
     from your_table 
     where data @? '$.prices.*.price'
     order by id,price desc)as subquery;









[    {        "id": 2,        "price": 86    },    {        "id": 3,        "price": 41    },    {        "id": 1,        "price": 20    }]



Otherwise, if you were showing a dict as returned by the client library while on SQL level those are supposed to be separate rows:
select id,price
from(select distinct on(id)id
           ,jsonb_path_query(data,'$.prices.*.price')as price
     from your_table 
     where data @? '$.prices.*.price'
     order by id,price desc)as subquery
order by price desc;




id
price




2
86


3
41


1
20




I was able to come up with another way of doing it but this one made more sense and gave me more of an understanding as you explained each step. Thanks!

It sounds like you want to use the jsonpath feature. That is, jsonb_path_query with the 2nd argument '$.data.prices.*.price'.  But it isn't clear what you want to happen if there is more than one, or less than one, match.

That looks promising and may answer my question but to clarify what you said in your last sentence, there should always be at least one match and if there happens to be more than one parent key, return the price value that is highest as well as sort on that value.

Just disassemble the JSON array, select id and price(by level), then with a window function get the max price for a correspondent id, like:
select jsonb_agg(row_to_json(t)) resulting_json
from (
with jsonb_data as (
    select jsonb_array_elements(data_field) df 
    from example
)
select 
    df ->> 'id' id, 
    max(jsonb_path_query_first(df, '$.**{4}')::integer) 
    over (partition by df -> 'id') price    
from jsonb_data
order by 2 desc) t;




resulting_json




[{"id": "2", "price": 86}, {"id": "3", "price": 41}, {"id": "1", "price": 20}]



Fiddle to test
